# Counting UTF-16 characters

Tags: c++, unicode

Lets say that I have a array of UTF-16 bytes. How would I count how many characters are in the array of UTF-16 bytes? The array can also be inside of a boundary. For example, lets say that there is a 4 byte UTF-16 character, and only 3 of the 4 bytes are read into a buffer. I then try counting that 3 byte buffer. How would I detect that there is not enough bytes?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So, do you mean codepoints?

Comment: Well I tried using the .NET implementation. However, I was curious because it gets the character amount by shifting the byte count to the right by 1, but iterates the entire bytes to see if there is boundary. So I am trying to find faster way

Comment: Byte count shifted right by 1 is not character count, it is code point count.

Comment: @ChristopherYeleighton However that's what GetCharCount for Unicode returns

Comment: https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#utf-16-surrogate-pairs

Comment: You can't count UTF-16 byte by byte, you *have* to count them in pairs.  If you try to read odd numbers of bytes you'll instantly be in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

4-byte UTF-16 characters are called *surrogate pairs*, and all surrogate pairs start with a code unit in the range 0xD800 to 0xDBFF inclusive.  To count the number of characters (aka code points) in a UTF-16 string you therefore want to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
char_count = 0;
string_pos = 0;

while (!end_of_string)
{
    code_unit = input_string [string_pos];
    ++char_count;
    if (code_unit >= 0xd800 && code_unit <= 0xdbff)
        string_pos += 2;
    else
        ++string_pos;
}
```

To detect an incomplete surrogate pair, just check if there are any code units left in the string after detecting the lead-in value.  You might also want to check for invalid surrogate pairs.

Wikipedia has a good write-up on UTF-16 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Comment: Hmm. How would I check if a byte is the start of a unicode character?

Comment: @BiBi you can't, that's why my comment on the question states you need to read them in pairs.  Only the even numbered bytes can tell you.  This answer assumes you've already combined the bytes into 16-bit quantities.

Comment: Characters are not code points.  It may take several code points to build a character.

Answer (score -2):

Examine the state of the decoder.  If the state is READY then it is enough, otherwise it is not enough.  Of course, you need to maintain the state with each incoming code point.